# Using a shared_ptr with objects

Tags: c++, object, shared-ptr

I have a struct named `Board`. In this struct, I have an attribute called `parentBoard` which is supposed to just point to another `Board` object. I was originally going to use regular pointers to do this, but I found something in the stl for `shared_pointers`. If I define the shared_ptr like this: `shared_ptr<Board> pointerToParentBoard;`, how can I make this point to an already defined `Board` object?

I have already tried this, hoping it was just like a regular pointer:

```
pointerToNewBoard = &board1;
```

But alas, it isn't and I can't find anything on Google to help. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: In my project, memory leaks are very costly and it might be difficult to keep track of all the allocated memory, which is why I'm wanting to use smart pointers.

Comment: Shared pointers can only be used with objects that are constructed in dynamic scope. That's what shared pointers are all about. It's unclear from the description whether `board` is constructed in dynamic scope, or not. But if it's not, it's not going to work. Shared pointers are not "just like a regular pointer". If they were, there won't be any point to them. Shared pointers are for a very specific purpose, which should be fully explained in your C++ book.

Comment: Does it work if you call the constructor `pointerToNewBoard = std::shared_ptr(board1);`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, the `board1` object is dynamically created.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah No.

Comment: Do you really need `std::shared_ptr`? Is more than one object going to be pointing at the same board and each one being responsible for deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

Keep parent pointer raw but manage children by smart pointer.

```
struct Board
{
   private:
   std::shared_pointer<std::vector<Board>> children;
   Board * parent;
   public:
   Board(Board * ptr=nullptr):children(std::make_shared<std::vector<Board>>())
   {
        // don't add here, it becomes recursive
        parent = ptr;
   }

   // or add here
   Board addNew()
   {
       children->push_back(Board(this));
       return children->back();
   }

   // or add here
   void add(Board * ptr)
   {
       children->push_back(*ptr);
   }

   // make parent
   // should only use if "this" is a root node
   void makeParent(Board * b)
   {
       b.add(this);
       if(nullptr==parent)
           parent = b;
       else
           throw std::runtime_error("This node is not root. Can't change parent.");
   }

}
```

this way, children can be independently deallocated automatically when only their parent is deallocated, meaning that a child's scope is its parent.

Also don't forget to add constructors for rule of three/five.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A couple things I should've made clearer:

1) `Board` is a struct, not a class.
2) I only need to traverse backwards. I don't need to know what the children are, only the parent of each board.

Comment: Ok will fix this. Struct is nearly a class with default public access anway.

Comment: There is a lot of naked pointers here. My smartphone camera would blur most of this by reasons of decency.

Comment: Let me tidy these then.

Comment: @MatthewVanlandingham the only difference between `struct` and `class` in C++ is that members are public by default in `struct` and private by default in `class`. Otherwise they are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using raw pointers in c++ to avoid accidental memory leaks. To avoid cyclic reference, use std::weak_ptr for the parent member.

```
struct Board
{
private:
    std::weak_ptr<Board> _parent;

public:
    Board(std::shared_ptr<Board> parent = nullptr) {
        _parent = parent;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Board> getParent() {
        std::shared_ptr<Board> strong = std::shared_ptr<Board>(_parent);
        return strong ? strong : nullptr;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Board> traverseToRoot() {
        std::shared_ptr<Board> grand_parent = getParent();
        std::shared_ptr<Board> parent = grand_parent;
        while (!grand_parent) {
            parent = grand_parent;
            grand_parent = grand_parent->getParent();
        }
        return parent;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Board> greatgrandparent = make_shared <Board>();
    std::shared_ptr<Board> grandparent = make_shared <Board>(greatgrandparent);
    std::shared_ptr<Board> parent = make_shared <Board>(grandparent);
    auto great_great_grand_parent = parent->traverseToRoot();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't need to keep track of the children Boards, only the parent boards. Also, could you explain the advantages of a weak_pointer vs a shared_pointer? Thanks!

Comment: std::weak_ptr is a non-owning reference to an object that is managed by the shared_ptr and you can derived a weak_ptr directly from a smart_ptr. Having the children pointers will assist in traversing both ways later.